# Prime Number Calculations Help Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, array-algorithms

I am a novice, please excuse my lack of organization.
Okay, so what I did was I made an array filled with all the prime numbers between 8 and 100. What I want to do now is make another array that finds all the prime numbers between 101-200. So allow me to explain how I did the first part:

//Prime1 is an dynamic integer array which stores all the prime numbers between 8 and 100

```
int arrayCounter = 0; 
for(int primeTest = 8; primeTest<=100; primeTest++)
{
    if(primeTest%2!=0 && primeTest%3!=0 && primeTest%5!=0 && primeTest%7!=0)
    { 
        Prime1.add(primeTest); //adds the prime numbers to array
        arrayCounter = arrayCounter +1; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1; 
    } 
}
```

Now back to the main issue, rather than writing "if(primeTest % "prime#" !=0)" I would like to be able to use modulus through the entire Prime1 array and see if all the values do not equal zero... Let me elaborate.

```
for(int primeTest2 = 101; primeTest2 <= 200; primeTest2++)
{
    for(int arrayCounter2 = 0; arrayCounter2 < Prime1.size(); arrayCounter2++)
    {      
        if(primeTest2 % Prime1.get(arrayCounter2) != 0 )
        {
            Prime2.add(primeTest2);
        }
    }
}
```

//please forgive any missing braces

^^So what happens here is that I take a value starting at 101 and modulus it with the first value of the Prime1 array. As you know, this may give me a false positive because 11 (the first prime number in the array) may still show true even with numbers which are not prime. This is why I need to be able to test a number with all the values in the array to ensure that it cannot be divided by any other prime number (meaning that it is prime).

Comment: Being a novice is no excuse for lack of organization.

Comment: Why do you try to reinvent the wheel? Look how [primes should be checked](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514680/prime-number-test-java

Comment: @fed.pavlo: Practice, fun and profit are very valid reasons to reinvent wheels. In this case it's probably only practice though...

Answer (score 1):

Your method is extremely inefficient, nevertheless, here is how you can fix it:

```
for (int primeTest2 = 101; primeTest2 <= 200; primeTest2++)
{
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int arrayCounter2 = 0; arrayCounter2 < Prime1.size(); arrayCounter2++)
    {
        if (primeTest2 % Prime1.get(arrayCounter2) == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (prime)
        Prime2.add(primeTest2);
}
```

BTW, for the first set of prime numbers, it is sufficient to use 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13.

Answer (score 1):

Take a boolean and set it to true. If the number can be divided by any of your primes from 8 to 100 without a remainder, than set it to false. If it is still true after testing every number, add the tested number to the Prime2 array, otherwise continue with the next number. Example:

```
for(int n = 101; n <= 200; n++)
{
    boolean isPrime = true;

    for(Integer p : Prime1)
        if(n % p == 0 )
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }

    if(isPrime)
            Prime2.add(n);
}
```

But there are better alorithms out there to check if a number is prime or to calculate alle primes below n. For example the Sieve of Eratosthenes.