# How can I check for prime numbers?

Tags: java, primes

What is the simplest way to do this, preferably without lists or maps?
I've tried turning the wikipedia pseudocode into real code but I don't understand the second half after the new line at all.

```
function is_prime(n : integer)
if n ≤ 1
    return false
else if n ≤ 3
    return true
else if n mod 2 = 0 or n mod 3 = 0
    return false

let i ← 5
while i×i ≤ n
    if n mod i = 0 or n mod (i + 2) = 0
        return false
    i ← i + 6
return true
```

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to rewrite this code in Java. You don't need to use any data structure, just implement this.

Answer (score 1):

First off, here's that function converted to java:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (n <= 3) {
        return true;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    int i = 5;
    while (i * i <= n) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        i += 6;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The second half is the part that iterates from the lowest unchecked number (5, because multiples of 2 are already checked, as are 0, 1, and 3) to the square root of `n` (anything greater than the square root would have to be multiplied by something less than the square root to equal `n`), checking each number `i` to see if `n` is evenly divisible by `i`.

Comment: this question can be found very easily since it has been discussed many times, this is a duplicate, did you use google before asking a question?.     [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514680/prime-number-test-java   [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420602/how-can-i-check-for-prime-numbers And thats only stack links.

Comment: @MRK187 I meant it should be an comment on the question, not on an answer...

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPrime(39));
}
```